# PostgreSQL to Oracle Database with Oracle GoldenGate 11.2.1

Tags: oracle, postgresql, synchronization, oracle-golden-gate

I've spent 2 days to sync postgresql database to oracle. Read few books, googled many times..
1. I have setup PostgreSQL on CentOS 6.5 (A) also installed oracle database on this VPS. copied GoldenGate to it.
2. I have already setup 2 oracle VPS using Goldengate and setup as Source (B) and Target (C). I'm trying to sync PostgreSQL to Target VPS.
3. GoldenGate runs on A server without error.

The problem is when I setting up it requires ODBC config (page 14). I'm new to PostgreSQL so little confusing for this.. 
Also when I google i find only to postgresql from oracle.

Main doc I'm following is http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35209_01/doc.1121/e29642.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Actually I have found Oracle Golden Gate new features https://blogs.oracle.com/dataintegration/resource/2013-DIFamily/OGG_WinUnix_Rel_Notes_11.2.1.0.7.pdf

Oracle Golden Gate don't support what I want to do.

They say:

Oracle GoldenGate introduces support for PostgreSQL. This support includes the mapping, manipulation, 
filtering, and delivery of data from other types of databases to a PostgreSQL database. Oracle GoldenGate 
does not support the capture of data from PostgreSQL to other PostgreSQL databases or to other kinds of 
databases.

Comment: Hi there! So did you find any workaround? I'm having the same problem... :(

Comment: The solution is Postgre to MySQL and MySQL to Oracle. PostGre has foreign table feature.

Answer (score 0):

GoldenGate does not support Postgres as a source - only target.

Check out Attunity for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres support was only for delivery in Oracle GoldenGate 12.2.  Oracle is working on a full capture/delivery support for Postgres.  It will be out in a later release post 19c.  Please check the OTN website for versions.